# Column Split Sum over a single ID

Tags: sql, select, sum, teradata

Similar to a question I had earlier

Having this table

```
ID, Year, Revenue 
1, 2009, 10 
1, 2009, 20 
1, 2010, 20 
2, 2009, 5 
2, 2010, 50
2, 2010, 1
```

Is it possible to make a query that results in something similar to this?

```
ID 2009 2010
1  30   20        
2  5    51
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `PIVOT`

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

And here: [How can i use pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891039/how-can-i-use-pivot)

**Update**

With the new info (Teradata DB), here's the solution:

```
select 
  ID,
  Sum(CASE When Year = 2009 then Revenue ELSE 0 END) as Y2009,
  Sum(CASE When Year = 2010 then Revenue ELSE 0 END) as Y2010
From
  YourTable
Group by ID
```

Comment: Sadly the database is not Microsoft but Teradata

Comment: The updated solution will produce the result you are attempting to accomplish. The challenge is that for every year of data added to the database you end up having to modify the SQL to include it in your results.

Comment: @Rob One solution for that is having your app assemble the SQL query string.